# Wrap a sub-string with paragraph tag in a string in content editable div

Tags: javascript, replace

Heres the html -:

```
<div contenteditable="true">I am a good person</div>
```

Now how to i wrap the sub-string which starts at `index 7 to index 17` with a paragraph tag, so that the result is like this -: `<div contenteditable="true">I am a <p>good person</p> </div>`

Comment: Play with the innerHTML , though its not the acceptable approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somethinng like:

```
function wrapSubstring(sourceString, subString, tag) {
    return sourceString.replace(new RegExp("(" + subString + ")", "g"), "<" + tag" + ">$1</" + tag + ">");
}
```

The above will replace all instances of subString in sourceString.

***Important***
If subString can contain arbitrary text you'll need to quote subString.
See: [How to escape regular expression in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript)

And a less generic implementation:

```
// Wrap a subString of sourceString with the given tag
// starting at startIndex(inclusive) and going to endIndex(exclusive)
function wrapSubstring(sourceString, tag, startIndex, endIndex) {
    return sourceString.substring(0, startIndex)
        + "<" + tag + ">"
        + sourceString.substring(startIndex, endIndex)
        + "</" + tag + ">"
        + (endIndex ? sourceString.substring(endIndex) : "");
}
```

Here's a sample call using jquery:

```
var $element = $('#someId');
$element.html(wrapSubstring($element.html(), 'p', 7, 17);
```

Comment: there can be more than one matching substrings. I just wanna replace that one that starts at index 7 and ends that index 17. I also know jquery, but dont know how to implement this one

Comment: @RayZ Updated with a less generic sample using indexes to wrap one substring.